# CSS - Keeping a select on the same line as an unordered list

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep a segmented control (unordered list) and a select on the same line, but I can't figure out how to do it. I thought it was as simple as using display:inline-block;

I put everything in a span:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">
    <select name="my_select1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
    <ul class="segmentedControl">
      <li class="selected">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <select name="my_slect2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
</span>
```

My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/39/

Am I missing something trivial on what I need to set in CSS?

Edit: I think I can do it by using divs/float, is this stupid to do?

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <select name="my_select1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <ul class="segmentedControl">
      <li class="selected">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <select name="my_slect2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<span>` elements may not have `<ul>` element children. More importantly, the `<ul>` uses a block level display.

Comment: What should I be using then? Switching span to a div doesn't solve it

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me... What browser are you using as I know older versions of IE have problems with inline-block.

Comment: With what you originally did, only the outer span was display:inline-block. All of its child elements were still display: block. Using div/float is fine as well. I personally don't see anything wrong in using a combination of div/float to align elements in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Set select and ul to `float:left;`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syw86/)

Comment: What do you mean by working properly? Your question was about displaying them in the same line, right? This is just a small example how you can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `inline-box`.  The following modification will do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/41/

```
.segmentedControl {
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack:justify;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    width:100px;
    height:22px;
}
```

However, there's not really a reason to use Flexbox for this purpose (not to mention you've only included properties from an outdated spec).  You can get the same effect using `display: inline-table` and `display: table-cell`, which has a lot wider support than Flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/42/

```
.segmentedControl {
    display: inline-table;
    width:100px;
    height:22px;
}


.segmentedControl > li
{
    display: table-cell;

    border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
    border-left: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius:0px;

    text-align: center;

    background: #fbfbfb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #bdbdbd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fbfbfb), color-stop(100%,#bdbdbd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#bdbdbd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#bdbdbd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#bdbdbd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbfbfb 0%,#bdbdbd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fbfbfb', endColorstr='#bdbdbd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: #6b6b6b;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `ul` in a  `div` like below and just add `display:inline-block;` to the "test" class.

```
 <select name="my_select1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
 <div class="test">
    <ul class="segmentedControl">
      <li class="selected">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <select name="my_slect2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

`UL` is still a block level element by default. You probably want to override that.

Comment: But I need it to be block right? In order for the segmented control to function properly